# Editing ESRI Python Toolbox in Spyder With Syntax Checking

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, esri, arcmap

When working with an [ESRI Python Toolbox](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm) it would be helpful if Spyder's editor window recognized `.pyt` files. My current workaround (to use syntax-checking) involves using a temporary `.py` file, opened in a new tab, and the code is copy/pasted back and forth for editing and saving (see screenshot).

Is there a setting in Spyder to extend the recognizable file types?

[image: Split-screen View of Spyder .py and .pyt]